# Jupyter doesn't recognize module pip just installed

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the package [here](https://pypi.org/project/tti/) and after successfully installing it using pip as confirmed in cmd, I can't import it in jupyter, what am I doing wrong?  I am on windows.

[image]

[image]

I have already restarted jupyter, please help.  I am on python 3.9.2.

[image]

Jupyter is 3.0.10

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by install jupyter from pip instead of downloading it from the internet